# Раскрывающийся список jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Имеется такая структура:

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<ul></ul>
<li></li>
<ul></ul>
</ul>
```

Как написать скрипт jquery для скрытия и раскрытия `li>ul`
Что имею сейчас:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    $('ul').click(function (event) {
        $(this).children("ul").slideToggle() ;
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Он соответственно открывает всех `children` предыдущего `ul`.

Comment: у вас неправильная html структура - в li необходимо влаживать sub ul - http://jsfiddle.net/hbd37exL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас неправильная html структура - в `li` необходимо влаживать sub `ul`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#list > li').click(function (event) {
        $(this).children("ul").slideToggle();
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

```css
#list {
}
#list > li {
}
#list > li > ul {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
    <li>list 1
        <ul>
            <li>sublist</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>list 2
        <ul>
            <li>sublist</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Хорошее решение, и даже новичку в данной области более менее понятно что выполняют эти функции jquery. Но я обнаружил баг в использовании этого кода... По неизвестным причинам после нажатия на li действительно открывается children но и скролит страницу в верх до конца, когда закрываешь список так же скролит